# Qt QML Have TabButton Get Its Own Index

Tags: qt, tabs, qml

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45461335/set-qml-tabbar-tab-color) shows how to change the color of a `TabButton` depending on if it is the current index:

```
 color: tabBar.currentIndex == 1 ? "purple" : "lightblue"
```

However, this requires  hard-coding each button with `currentIndex == 0` then `currentIndex == 1`. It seems like each button or its parent layout should know what its index is. I would like to introduce `CustomTabButton` control with a LOT of customization for visuals and have two options:

1. Add a property to the CustomTabButton called index and then set it individually
2. Programmatically get the index to avoid hard coding 1,2,3... for checking if it is the current index.

Is there a proper way?

Comment: Did you try it? Yes, you can add a property called `index`, and yes you can then programatically check `(currentIndex == index)`. What part do you need help with?

Comment: @JarMan It seems like there should already be a property of TabButton indicating what its index is, or that a field `Layout.index` or `parent.index` should be available. However, the only way I have so far is to add `property int index: 0` to a custom control and then specify it for each. However, these numbers are automatically assigned and the GUI already highlights correctly so _somewhere_ the index is already stored.

Comment: @jarman My failure to understand the index leads me to start the custom control with TabButton with property  `property int index: 0`  `property bool isSelected: bar.currentIndex == index` but that only works because I assume `bar` is available above it (neither `parent.currentIndex` nor `currentIndex` by itself apparently work) so this leads me to believe that ANOTHER property is needed to specify what TabBar is controlling it. But this is all already implicitly specified in the normal hierarchy so I seem to be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me, modifying an example from the Qt docs. `index` is an attached property from TabBar.

```
    TabBar {
        id: bar
        width: parent.width
        TabButton {
            text: (bar.currentIndex == TabBar.index) ? "AAA" : "aaa"
        }
        TabButton {
            text: (bar.currentIndex == TabBar.index) ? "BBB" : "bbb"
        }
        TabButton {
            text: (bar.currentIndex == TabBar.index) ? "CCC" : "ccc"
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a fantastic answer and absolutely answers the question. The solution is documented under "Attached Property Documentation" on the TabBar documentation page: "`TabBar.index: int` It is attached to each tab button of the TabBar." and _also_ found the documentation for `TabBar.tabBar` so we can remove the need for `id: bar` and get  `text: (TabBar.tabBar.currentIndex == TabBar.index) ? "AAA" : "aaa"` and thus understand how these secret parameters are automatically retained through attached properties.